# How to decompress tensorflow hub module in the terminal?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, terminal, compression, tensorflow-hub

> I want to download, decompress, and use a [pretrained model from tensorflow-hub](https://tfhub.dev/google/efficientnet/b1/classification/1)

After downloading I end up with a **1.tar.tar** file, which I probably need to extract / decompress in order to be able to use it.
I can't wrap my head around how, I am working in a Linux terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If your tar file is compressed using tar compression, use this command to decompress it. Make sure to be in the directory of the tar.tar file, it will decompress everything into the directory you are currently in.

```
$ tar xvzf 1.tar.tar
```

Where,

`x`: This option tells tar to extract the files.

`v`: The “v” stands for “verbose.” This option will list all of the files one by one in the archive.

`z`: The z option is very important and tells the tar command to uncompress the file.

`f`: This options tells tar that you are going to give it a file name to work with.

**Nice to know:**
A tarball is a group or archive of files that are bundled together using the tar command and have the .tar file extension.